# coldfusion - parsing a string date into datetime format

Tags: coldfusion

We receive an XML file with a date node as follows:

```
<createdDate>1/11/2008 7:04:28 a.m.</createdDate>
```

Dates are UK format dd/mm/yyy, so 1/11/2008 is 1st November 2008.

We run a coldfusion function to parse the xml and insert into the database. The relevant database field is of datetime datatype and needs to remain that way. How would I format this string representation of the date into a format the database will accept?

Comment: what version of CF you are running?

Comment: Have you tried the [`parseDateTime`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ParseDateTime) or [`lsParseDateTime`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/LSParseDateTime) functions?

Comment: I would suggest asking the provider of the XML file to change the date format to something more standardised.

Comment: I agree with @andrewdixon. If you are in control of the XML, then use a portable date/time format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an ideal situation, but the format you are getting data especially dots in am/pm strings make it hard to read and on top of that it comes in UK Date format. This can help:

```
<cfset x="21/11/2008 7:04:28 p.m.">
<cfset x=Replace(x,".","","All")>
<cfset y=LSDateFormat(x,"mm/dd/yyyy","English (UK)")>
<cfoutput>
    x====#x#
    <br/>y===#y#
<cfset z=CreateDateTime(Year(y),month(y),day(y),hour(x),minute(x),second(x))>
z====#z#
<cfset someDatevare=LSParseDateTime(x,"English (UK)")>
</cfoutput>
```

**EDIT** As Leigh mentioned, removing periods or any other non-standard characters from the string and then LSParseDateTime  will return a date time object.

Comment: Yep, the non-standard periods in "am/pm" are what prevent CF from implicitly converting the string. That side, once removed, it is more efficient to use [`LSParseDateTime()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-70e3.html) like @Antony suggested. Unlike `LSDateFormat`, `LSParseDateTime` already returns a date object. So you could skip the `CreateDateTime` call and implicit string/date conversions.

Comment: Good suggestion Leigh. Adding that in answer, so that this can help to future readers.